# Cannot run Vue app after multiple npm audit fix

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

I wanted to solve a problem vulnerabilities problem and now my app does not run.

I get this error message:

This dependency was not found:

- firebase in ./src/main.js, ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--0-1!./src/components/Navigation.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js and 1 other

To install it, you can run: npm install --save firebase
Error from chokidar (C:): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "poker-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "chart.js": "^3.6.2",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "firebase": "^9.6.1",
    "generatorics": "^1.1.0",
    "itertools": "^1.7.1",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-chartkick": "^0.6.1",
    "vue-echarts": "^6.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0"
  }
}
```

Anyone know what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting the node_modules folder then running:

```
npm cache clean --force  
npm install
```

Take a look on the warnings during the install as they can give you some clue about version incompatibility between packages

Comment: It is not working unfortunetly. I get the same message witch i wanted to solve before (34 vulnerabilities (22 moderate, 12 high)) and then got this error.